# Как получить тип Enum?

Tags: c#

Как получить тип от которого наследуется enum?

Например такой enum:

```cs
public enum MyEnum : long
{
  Foo,
  Bar
}
```

Comment: А какой в этом смысл, если он известен на этапе компиляции?

Comment: На этапе компиляции мы не знаем. Необходимо получить какой тип значения enum для правильной последующей обработки

Comment: `Enum.GetUnderlyingType`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enum.GetUnderlyingType](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.enum.getunderlyingtype)

```
Type type = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(MyEnum));
Console.WriteLine(type);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
System.Int64
```